# Adding users / virtual hosts to RabbitMQ from Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Is it possible to dynamically add users and virtual hosts to RabbitMQ using Java? I'm hoping to have the same functionality as `rabbitmqctl add_vhost` and `rabbitmqctl add_user`.

My RabbitMQ server is running on the same computer as my java code, but just executing them via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Comment: What command were you trying to run? What results or error messages did it yield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are RESTful [HTTP API](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api) in [Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) which is far more cleaner solution than running shell commands.